# Is there a recursive function / algorithm where using stack frames is unavoidable (cannot be made fully tail recursive)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tail-recursion

I'm trying to come up with examples of recursive algorithms / functions that cannot be rewritten in a way that avoids using lots of stack memory (i.e. cannot be made fully tail recursive nor rewritten using a loop that doesn't use a stack).  Do such functions exist?

I think quicksort might be a candidate, but am not sure if it can be rewritten to use a single tail-recursive function call.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try Ackermann function.

Answer (score 0):

Every algorithm that requires more than one call in the general case cannnot be done without a backtrack stack for iteration or growing the stack because the first call is not in tail position and will always have a continuation.

The simple fibonacci, quicksort and sum of tree are all in that category.